# Добавление выпадающего списка

Tags: javascript, css

На странице есть элемент:

```
                    <div class="trading__data-item increase">
                        <div class="trading__data-item__prefs"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
                        <div class="trading__data-title">Currency</div>
                        <div class="trading__data-balance">Value</div>                           
                        <div class="trading__data-state">0</div>
                    </div>
```

Css:

```
.trading__data-item {
    position: relative;
    border:1px solid #272E3D;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 25px 16px 16px;
    margin-left: 13px;
    width: 225px;
    height: 96px;
}
.trading__data-item__prefs {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 5px;
    width: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.trading__data-item__prefs span {
    height: 4px;
    width: 4px;
    background-color: #45506A;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    display: block;
}
.trading__data-item__prefs:hover span {background-color: #aaa;}
.trading__data-item__prefs span:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L8cp39u6/
Как сделать выпадающий список при клике на 3 точки, в правом верхнем углу блока? Т.е я кликаю на 3 точки, у меня появляется список, и при выборе определенного элемента из списка - я записываю нужное мне значение в блок `<div class="trading__data-balance">`
Что-то типо этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где выпадающий список и куда он должен выпадать?

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex его нет, можно ли его как-то присобачить туда?

Comment: @hu-fo-of-ex добавил пример, значения, которые буду присваивать при определенном выбранном элементе в списке я буду загружать через php, мне просто нужно условие, что если выбран 1ый эл списка, то у блока `<div class="trading__data-balance">` такое-то значение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'item-1',
    balance: 33,
    state: 44,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'item-2',
    balance: 100,
    state: 4,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'item-3',
    balance: 555,
    state: 666,
  }

]

const items = document.querySelectorAll('.trading__data-item');

items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (
      e.target.classList.contains('trading__data-item__prefs') ||
      e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('trading__data-item__prefs')) {
      item.querySelector('ul').classList.toggle('hidden');
    }

    if (e.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
      item.querySelector('ul').classList.toggle('hidden');
      data.forEach(el => {
        if (e.target.dataset.title == el.title) {
          item.querySelector('.trading__data-title').innerText = el.title;
          item.querySelector('.trading__data-balance').innerText = el.balance;
          item.querySelector('.trading__data-state').innerText = el.state;
        }
      })
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.trading__data {
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 3px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.trading__data-item {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #272E3D;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 25px 16px 16px;
  margin-left: 13px;
  width: 225px;
  height: 96px;
}

.trading__data-item__prefs {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
  width: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.trading__data-item__prefs span {
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #45506A;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  display: block;
}

.trading__data-item__prefs:hover span {
  background-color: #aaa;
}

.trading__data-item__prefs span:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.trading__data-title {
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

li:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="trading__data tab__block">
  <div class="trading__data-item increase" id="block_0">
    <div class="trading__data-item__prefs"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
    <div class="trading__data-title">Currency 0</div>
    <div class="trading__data-balance" id="bal_0">Value 0</div>

    <div class="trading__data-state">0</div>

    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><button data-title="item-1">1</button></li>
      <li><button data-title="item-2">2</button></li>
      <li><button data-title="item-3">3</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="trading__data-item increase" id="block_1">
    <div class="trading__data-item__prefs"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
    <div class="trading__data-title">Currency 1</div>
    <div class="trading__data-balance" id="bal_1">Value 1</div>

    <div class="trading__data-state">0</div>

    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><button data-title="item-1">1</button></li>
      <li><button data-title="item-2">2</button></li>
      <li><button data-title="item-3">3</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="trading__data-item increase" id="block_2">
    <div class="trading__data-item__prefs"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
    <div class="trading__data-title">Currency 2</div>
    <div class="trading__data-balance" id="bal_2">Value 2</div>

    <div class="trading__data-state">0</div>

    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><button data-title="item-1">1</button></li>
      <li><button data-title="item-2">2</button></li>
      <li><button data-title="item-3">3</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="trading__data-item increase" id="block_3">
    <div class="trading__data-item__prefs"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
    <div class="trading__data-title">Currency 3</div>
    <div class="trading__data-balance" id="bal_3">Value 3</div>

    <div class="trading__data-state">0</div>

    <ul class="hidden">
      <li><button data-title="item-1">1</button></li>
      <li><button data-title="item-2">2</button></li>
      <li><button data-title="item-3">3</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, то что нужно, спасибо огромное! А вы не могли бы еще адаптировать это под несколько блоков    `<div class="trading__data-item increase">` при условии, что у каждого будет уникальный id?

Comment: Выложи полную верстку этих всех блоков со всеми id и классами

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h2zk6ygm/, вот

Comment: @Ayurpwnz поменял ответ

Comment: Да, очень выручили, спасибо большое

Comment: дико извиняюсь, не могли бы вы еще добавить, чтобы выпадающий список закрывался после выбора какого-либо элемента в нем, а не по клику на 3 точки

Comment: @Ayurpwnz обновил